# codeigniter data not showing when entering $user_id and data is showing when putting directly user_id no which is "1"

Tags: codeigniter

what does var dump does in codeigniter,
and if i want and array of data from database not from user input to stored in session how will i get data from db to stored in session

```
<?php
class Login extends MY_Controller{
public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('public/admin_login');
}

public function admin_login()
{

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','User Name','required|alpha|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');    

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<p class='text-danger'>","</php>");
    if($this->form_validation->run() )
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $this->load->model('loginmodel');
        $login_id = $this->loginmodel->login_valid($username , $password);
        if($login_id)
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_id','login_id');
            return redirect('admin/dashboard');
}
        else
        {
            echo "password dont match";
        }
    }
    else
        {
    $this->load->view("public/admin_login");

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is inspect the value of your user_id so after you assign it, you can simply echo $user_id or even use var_dump($user_id).

I don't know where you are setting that session value for user_id, but I am suspecting it's null. But you will find that out by trying what  I suggested.

```
public function articles_list()
    {
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        var_dump($user_id); // Added for debug - remove me later
        // die(); // optional in case we do need to stop the execution to view the var_dump
        $query = $this->db
                            ->select('title')
                            ->from('articles')
                            ->where('user_id',$user_id)// here when in place of $user_id i'm entering directly user_id no '1'its showing articles but when entering $user_id showing no result found//
                            ->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean `$this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$login_id);` ?

By the way,
you can consider this:

In Articlesmodel,

```
 public function articles_list($user_id )    { .. }
```

and

In Admin,

```
 public function dashboard()
  {

        $this->load->model('articlesmodel','articles');
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $articles = $this->articles->articles_list($user_id);
        $this->load->view('admin/dashboard',['articles'=>$articles]);
    }
```

A nicer design that not to access session data in your model class.